# Slow (10 Mb/s) wired connection on 18.04

Tags: networking, 18.04, drivers, ethernet

I'm experiencing a very slow Ethernet connection on Ubuntu 18.04 using an Intel I211 gigabit network connection. The same port / cable gets to 100 Mb/s using a different Ubuntu PC (with different Ethernet controller). Out put of `lspci -knn | grep Eth -A3` is:

```
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd I211 Gigabit Network Connection [1458:e000]
    Kernel driver in use: igb
    Kernel modules: igb
```

output from `ethtool enp4s0`:

```
    Supported ports: [ TP ]
    Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                            100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                            1000baseT/Full 
    Supported pause frame use: Symmetric
    Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
    Supported FEC modes: Not reported
    Advertised link modes:  Not reported
    Advertised pause frame use: Symmetric
    Advertised auto-negotiation: No
    Advertised FEC modes: Not reported
    Speed: 100Mb/s
    Duplex: Full
    Port: Twisted Pair
    PHYAD: 1
    Transceiver: internal
    Auto-negotiation: off
    MDI-X: off (auto)
Cannot get wake-on-lan settings: Operation not permitted
    Current message level: 0x00000007 (7)
                   drv probe link
    Link detected: yes
```

when I set autoneg on it defaults to duplex half and speed is approximately 7 Mb/s (upload), setting autoneg off and duplex full I get 12 Mb/s

I'm out of ideas how to fix this and would very much appreciate any help.

Comment: Sure that you got bits vs bytes right? 12 MB/s == 100 Mb/s

Comment: apologies - it should be Mb/s... edited